# Iterate through a hash table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashtable

I am using a node.js script to migrate some data from a MySQL instance to MongoDB.  I am in a situation where I would like to iterate through each entry in a hash table and then call a function after all the items are done processing.

In the past I have done this with arrays using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) which has worked great, but this does not appear to work with hash tables unfortunately.

How can I iterate through each entry in a hash table and call a specific function when the last entry has been processed?

Comment: So I'm a little confused here. In JS, every object _is_ a hashtable. Is there something you are specifically doing that prevents you from simply doing a `for` loop?

Comment: Is it possible to know when all items have finished processing using a standard for loop?

Comment: So your challenge is that you are performing async processing for each hash table entry & you want to know when they are all done. Clearly, the answer below is the correct one then.

Comment: Yep, that's why I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(Object.keys(hash), function(key, callbackAfterEach) {
  // Do your thing here with hash[key]
  callbackAfterEach();
}, callbackAfterAll);
```